# Solidworks API / Macro to create configuration with a "Description"

Tags: solidworks, solidworksapi

Is there a way to create a new configuration with something written into "description" of the configuration properties?

i used AddConfiguration3 but there is no argument for "description" in it.

---

```
Sub main()
   
    Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Dim strNumber As String
    
    
    
    
    
    strNumber = InputBox("please enter name of config", "config")
    swModel.AddConfiguration3 strNumber, Empty, Empty, 0
    
    
    
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution:

```
Sub main()
    'get access
    Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel As ModelDoc2
    Dim ConfigMgr As ConfigurationManager
    
    'set
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set ConfigMgr = swModel.ConfigurationManager
    Dim strNumber As String
    Dim strDescription As String
    
    
    
    'Get number and description
    
    
    strNumber = InputBox("enter number", "Number")
    strDescription = InputBox("enter description", "description")
    ConfigMgr.AddConfiguration2 strNumber, Empty, Empty, 1, "", strDescription, False
    
    
    
        
End Sub
```